Few questions surrounding CPI, TRPO and PPO
I was studying the papers in quite some detail in the past few weeks and ther are some questions that I couldn't find an answer for yet.

In the TRPO paper is $\nabla_{\theta}\eta(\pi_\theta)$ really just the policy gradient, so esentially $\eta(\pi_\theta) = J(\theta)$ in most literature?
Does the final TRPO algorithm (which is NPG + Trust Region) give a guarantee on monotonic improvement? The theoretical result of the paper gives a gurantee, but since we use a lot of approximation for the surrogate objective I wonder if the guarantee is still there, although I understand that the trust region method wants to preserve as much as possible of the guarantee.
In the PPO paper it is stated the $\mathrm{L}^\mathrm{CPI}$ is porposed in the paper about Conservative Policy Iteration, but I don't see any signs of using importance sampling in the paper. Does anyone know what the authours refer to here?
In the PPO paper it says $\mathrm{L}^\mathrm{CPI} = \mathrm{L}^\mathrm{CLIP}$ to first order around $\theta_\mathrm{old}$ and gets different as $\theta$ moves away from $\theta_\mathrm{old}$. Can anyone provide a proof that this is the case?
Since NPG is proposed as a special case of TRPO, why doesn't it use importance sampling? Also to show that NPG is a special case of TRPO we would need to show that the linear approximation of $\sum_s \rho_{\text{old}}(s) \sum_a \pi_\theta(a|s) A_{\text{old}}(s,a)$ corresponds to the same objective as NPG right (which is the gradient of the objective)? Is there a proof of that?
Also in the TPRO paper the objective given by expanding $L_{\theta_\mathrm{old}}$ in (13) is missing the $\eta(\pi)$ term somehow.

